# Adding selected check box to arraylist

Tags: java

I'm pretty new/bad at Java and completely new to GUI. 
How do I add selected checkboxs to an arraylist? I've tried looking around but can't really find anything that helps.
Any help would be appreicated. Keep in mind I'm new to java my code will more than likely be pretty bad.

http://tinypic.com/r/11b6pno/8
Not sure if this help but might give an idea because I might have worded it wrong, when I click a procedure I want, it outputs that procedure onto the screen and I want to put those into an arraylist

```
public class testProcedures extends JPanel
{
    private static JLabel procedureLabel;
    private static JButton orderButton, resetButton, quitButton;
    private static JTextArea orderDetails;
    private static JCheckBox[] procedure;
    private static int NUM_PROCEDURES= 5;
    static JTextField patientIDField;


    public testProcedures()
    {
        super();
        patientIDField = new JTextField("Enter Patient ID Number", 25);
        add(patientIDField);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,300));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        add(pane, new Dimension(1,1));
        setVisible(true);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Procedures");
        frame.setContentPane(split);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);*/
    }

    public void selectProcedures()
    {
        procedureLabel = new JLabel("Select Procedures");
        procedure= new JCheckBox[NUM_PROCEDURES];
        procedure[0] = new JCheckBox("Extraction",false);
        procedure[1] = new JCheckBox("Filling",false);
        procedure[2] = new JCheckBox("Cleaning",false);
        procedure[3] = new JCheckBox("Crown",false);
        procedure[4] = new JCheckBox("X-Ray",false);


        orderButton = new JButton("Set Procedures");
        orderButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){



                        processOrder();
                    }
                });

        resetButton = new JButton("Reset Patient Procedures Form");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        resetForm();
                    } });

        quitButton = new JButton("Quit Program");
        quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

                        System.exit(0);
                    } });

        orderDetails = new JTextArea("Awaiting Procedures....",5,40);
        add(procedureLabel);
        for (int index=0; index < NUM_PROCEDURES;++index)
            add(procedure[index]);
        add(orderButton);
        add(resetButton);
        add(quitButton);
        add(orderDetails);
    }

    static void processOrder()
    {
        String order = "Procedures Selected:";
        boolean proceduresSelected= false;

        String patientID = patientIDField.getText();
        int patientNumb = Integer.parseInt(patientID);
        ArrayList<Patient> PatientList = DentistTabbed.getPatientList();
        ArrayList <Procedure> procList = new ArrayList<Procedure>();
        for (int index=0; index < NUM_PROCEDURES;++index)
            if (procedure[index].isSelected())
            {
                //here
                for(Patient pat: PatientList)
                {
                    if(pat.getPatientNumber()==patientNumb)
                    {

                        //pat.addProcedure(procedure);
                        //procList.add(procedure);

                    }
                }
                //here
                proceduresSelected = true;
                order += "\n"+ procedure[index].getLabel();
            }
        if (!proceduresSelected)
            order += "No procedure Selected.";
        order += ".";
        orderDetails.setText(order);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code for the `Procedure` class? Looks like you want to add _procedures_ (based on selections in the GUI), not the actual checkboxes to the list.

Comment: Theres really nothing in my Procedure class, I could add it if you want but its empty enough not sure theres anything in there useful

Answer (score 0):

A general solution:

```
checkBox.setSelected(true);
list.add(checkBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop, which will go through procedure array looking for selected CheckBoxes:

```
        ArrayList selected = new ArrayList();
        for(JCheckBox oneProcedure: procedure){
            if(singleProcedure.isSelected()){
                selected.add(singleProcedure);
            }
        }
```

However I wonder, why you need JCheckBox ArrayList? Maybe a chosen 'procedure' in String form would be enough?

```
        ArrayList<String> selected = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(JCheckBox oneProcedure: procedure){
            if(singleProcedure.isSelected()){
                selected.add(singleProcedure.getText());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the `Procedure` or `Patient` classes, I'm assuming you want the actual texts of the checkboxes instead of the checkboxes set to `Patient`s in a given `PatientList`:

```
//here
for (Patient pat: PatientList) {
    if (pat.getPatientNumber() == patientNumb) {
        Procedure proc = new Procedure(procedure[index].getText());
        pat.addProcedure(proc);

        // note that if you add the procedure to 
        // procList while looping through PatientList,
        // you will get duplicate treatments in the list if 
        // there are more than one patients
        procList.add(proc);
    }
}
//here
```